# How do I find the particular solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I find the particular solution for$$\cos(x)\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}-\sin(x)y=\sin^2(x)\cos(x)$$for $-\dfrac{\pi}{2}<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

given that $y(0)=9$.

I have now come to:

$ \dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{sin^3(x)}{cos(x)}$$+c=9$

$ \dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{sin^3(x)}{cos(x)}$ $=0$

Therefore $c=9$

Comment: In the first order linear case you don't even need to split into homogeneous/particular, you can explicitly construct the solution to an IVP by using an integrating factor. In this case the integrating factor is really "already there" if you look at the equation carefully...

Comment: Your answer is a "non-answer", as $y'$ is still unknown.

Comment: Don't change the question silently. This all that has been written obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos(x)\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}-\sin(x)y=\sin^2(x)\cos(x)$$
HINT :
$$d(\cos(x) y)=\sin^2(x)\cos(x)dx$$
Then, integrate.

Answer (score 2):

Read the equation as $$(y\cos x)'=\frac13(\sin^3x)'$$

and integrate. This will even give you the general solution.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly we need to find the Integrating Factor but before that divide the equation by $\cos x$. I'll denote it by $\mu$

$$\begin{aligned}\mu&=\exp \int \dfrac{-\sin x}{\cos x}\mathrm dx\\&=\exp \ln \cos x=\cos x\end{aligned}$$

Notice that this $\mu$ is specifically chosen so that the ODE becomes: $$\left(y\cos x\right)'=\left(\sin^2x\cos x\right)\implies y=\dfrac{1}{\cos x}\int\sin^2x\cos x\mathrm dx$$

Now all you have to do is integrate the expressino and find the value of the constant that makes the initial condition $y(0)=9$ true. Can you proceed?

Comment: You didn't have to delete your old answer. I was going to take off the downvote